# Conditionally start GenServer in tests

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have implemented a GenServer that listens to an external message queue via long polling. For that, I am starting the GenServer with the start of the application, i.e. within the `start/2` function of my `application.ex` file I specified an extra child in the supervisor list:

```
children = [
    supervisor(MyApp.Repo []),
    supervisor(MyAppWeb.Endpoint, []),
    supervisor(MyApp.MessageQueueGenServer, [])
]
```

This list is then started with:

```
Supervisor.start_link(children, [strategy: :one_for_one, name: MyApp.Supervisor])
```

---

Now I have the problem that the GenServer is of course also started when I am running some **(1)** database setup with `mix ecto.reset` or **(2)** tests with `mix test`.

For the tests **(2)** I could, e.g. only add `MyApp.MessageQueueGenServer` to the `children` list if `Mix.env != :test`.

But what about **(1)**? How to avoid starting my GenServer when running `mix ecto.reset`/`mix ecto.setup`/etc.?

Comment: Why does it matter that you are starting this `GenServer`? What would you gain from not starting it in these situations?

Comment: Because then I always have to ensure that the message queue is running and accessible even if I just want to run some database migration.

Comment: Processes in Elixir / Erlang are very light weight. If you removed that server from your startup, you wouldn't even notice. As for the database migrations, running the mix tasks will not actually start your application. Meaning that server is not started. The mix ecto tasks only start what they need.

Comment: First of all, thanks for trying to help so far.
My message queue is an external queue so sadly no Erlang process. Regarding the database migrations: let me be more precise here, `ecto.setup` is an alias for, .e.g. `run priv/repo/seeds.exs`which starts the GenServer.

Comment: All `GenServer`s are Erlang processes. You could make your actual connection to your queue as a message sent from the init function of your server. This would also allow you to handle reconnection however you wanted without the users even knowing that something went down. This is a fairly common way of handling external connections on the BEAM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue and I have it resolved with a configuration parameter.

*config/config.exs*

```
config :myapp, :children, [
  MyApp.Repo, MyAppWeb.Endpoint, MyApp.MessageQueueGenServer]
```

*config/dev.exs*

```
# config :myapp, :childen [] # tune it for dev here
```

*config/test.exs*

```
config :myapp, :children, [
  MyApp.Repo, MyAppWeb.Endpoint]
```

*your server file*

```
children = [
  :myapp
  |> Application.get_env(:children)
  |> Enum.map(&supervisor(&1, [])
]
```

---

*Sidenote:* you might want to consider using [modern style of children declaration](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#module-child_spec-1), since [`Supervisor.Spec`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.Spec.html) is deprecated, that way it would be even cleaner:

```
children = Application.get_env(:myapp, :children)
```

Comment: Great solution, thank you very much! Even if I use configuration parameters frequently in my application, I didn't thought about using it for the a GenServer as well.

Comment: I really like this solution. We are using libcluster, but don't want to start it in the dev environment, so this method let's us do that. One minor thing, shouldn't the :config atom used in the calls to Application.get_env instead be :children so it matches with the settings in the config files?